How can one be honest with oneself if one IS oneself?
My question is probably very basic, but it concerns a bit of a paradox/contradiction. In psychology it is a frequent refrain, "You aren't (or have to be) honest with yourself." I don't understand how it's ever possible to be dishonest with yourself in the first place, because you aren't two people. For instance:
"Hey, self, How ya doin'?"
"Good. I caught a large fish today"
"Bullshit."
I don't see that inner conversation happening.
Any philosophical thoughts on this question would help as it applies to kindness with the self or lack of delusion.

I should really get around to watching Kurosawa because I've only heard admiration for his work.

You probably also have never struggled to free yourself of any kind of addiction (cigarettes, sweets, drugs ... scrolling aimlesslessly thru social media)? If you had then you'd know that when sb says to themselves "I really want to stop now" it often is not reliable. This is also a form of lieing to oneself - more subtle, perhaps.

I am reminded: When Eckhart Tolle experienced his awakening he was near suicidal and repeating to himself through a whole tortured night I cannot live with myself, I cannot live with myself... Suddenly it hit him So are there two 'I's?? That hit was so powerful that it engendered a total existential collapse and his gloom lifted as the sun rose

On a common view, "self" is a complex entity parts/aspects of which can be at odds, see self-deception:"Most intentionalists introduce some sort of temporal or psychological partition to insulate self-deceivers from their deceptive stratagems. When self-deceivers are not consciously aware of what they truly believe or intend, it’s easier to see how they can play the role of the deceiver and the deceived." Other philosophers treat the notion of "self" as illusory and language involving it as merely metaphorical.

The call to "be honest with yourself" is just an exhortation to be more self-critical, to attempt to set aside any self-deceptive reasoning, and to recognize any cognitive dissonance one might be trying to protect oneself from grappling with.
Of course, one cannot ultimately control whether this is successful. But a considered, systematic approach can reveal lines of thinking and analysis that might have been missing when just making quick and more instinctive decisions.
